# How to setup reverse proxy in aws with statistic IP in aws with HA/AS

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, amazon-elb

the client can connect to domain ->elb->ec2 instances in AWS. some of client has to connect to statistic IP address instead of dynamic IP range. however AWS ELB does not support static IP address. So I want to setup on proxy layer that route the request to our existing elb or instances.
requirement:

1.AB zone HA availability

2.0 failure tolerant

3.attache static IP addresses (>= 2 elastic IP)

4.create new sub-domain in route 53 to route traffic to proxy setup

5.proxy layer can route the traffic to existing ELB

6.the proxy log can upstream to cloudwatch

7.can cater for 5 tps traffic

8.auto failover

9.can throttling in terms of tps/traffic

initially i am consider use NLB but NLB cannot connect to ALB/ELB.

Any best practise on setup proxy in AWS with static IP addresses.

Thanks

Comment: You can map the elb to some domain name and ask the client to use domain name instead of static IP.

Comment: no. my issue is I have already existing setup with domain with EC2 via dynamic IP. but client only can connect to static IP, so i want to know whether there is solution that have domain with static ip and traffic route to existing setup. thanks

Answer (score 0):

so far the solution :

1. create small EC2 instances and setup HA-proxy
2. domain map to elastic IP (more than one) to those HA proxy instances
3. use Nginx/apache web server as reverse proxy setup
4. config and route to existing public/private domain